# Common log4net logging for different instances of a dll

Tags: c#, .net, dll, log4net

I'm having trouble configuring log4net to work the way I want. I have a class library Library.dll that is used both by my application Mine.exe and a third party aplication Other.exe. I have another class library Util.dll that is used by both Mine.exe and Library.dll.

Mine.exe and Other.exe are run in parallel and I want the two instances of Library.dll to use the same logfile. It should also be separate from the logfile of Mine.exe. Util.dll should log to Library.dll logfile when called from Library.dll, and the Mine.exe logfile when called from Mine.exe.

**Edit: I guess that was a bit hard to follow, this is how I want i to work:**

Mine.exe logs to Mine.log
Other.exe doesn't log anything (third party application)
Mine.exe -> Library.dll logs to C:\Library.log
Other.exe -> Library.dll logs to C:\Library.log
Mine.exe -> Util.dll logs to Mine.log
Mine.exe -> Library.dll -> Util.dll logs to C:\Library.log
Other.exe -> Library.dll -> Util.dll logs to C:\Library.log 
Other.exe doesn't call Util.dll directly.

First I tried loading a custom log4net configuration in Library.dll, using:

```
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(new FileInfo("Library.log4net.config"));
```

But that resulted in Mine.exe also logging to the Library.dll logfile.

I then tried adding the following assembly attribute in Library.dll:

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.Repository("Library")]
```

That kept the logs separate, but then Util.dll logged to the Mine.exe logfile even when called from Library.dll. I guess I could use Repository("Util") in Util.dll, AliasReposity("Util", "Library") in Library.dll and AliasReposity("Util", "Mine") in Mine.exe but I actually have many class libraries in the project and would rather not go down that route.

Any ideas on how to get this working?

/Andreas

Comment: Let me make sure I have this straight: You want Main and Other's Library to log to log file "A", but Mine and Other themselves to log to files "B" and "C", and Util to whatever program's log file called it?

Comment: You should review your question. There seems to be some mixups with (at least) file extensions (Library.exe vs. Library.dll). Also, you probably should think about logging from an application (i.e. exe) perspective. That is, log everything from a single application into a single logfile, regardless of the DLLs that it is using. Mine.exe + all DLLs log to, say, "Mine.log". Other.exe + all DLLs log to "Other.log". Looks more intuitive to me, but of course that is just my 2 ct. :-)

Comment: Yes I got the extensions mixed up, fixed now. The reason I want a common log from Library.exe is that it is almost like a separate application and I want the logging intertwined in one file. In the old COM days, I would probably have made it an out of process server instead of a dll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not share log files to be honest.  There are all sorts of threading problems which you may encounter if you log to a file from two processes. Typically one log4net instance will just not be able to log if the other one is, so it will cause log entries to go missing.  Also if they are in the same log file, you need to chuck the process name in the log formatter so you know the source.  Sounds complicated.  By convention, I usually do the following:

- Reference the same log4net dllin each process.
- Create a log4net configuration section in process1.exe.config and process2.exe.config separately.
- Add a file appender for process1.exe.log and process2.exe.log separately in each config.

You get two files for two processes but this is easier to manage.  You can get log file watchers which can display both logs together (although I tend not to use that approach) such as: http://tailforwin32.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I postponed the requirement for Util.dll to be logged together with Library.dll and used the Repository attribute. It worked fine when running Mine.exe and Other.exe one at a time, but when running the applications simultaneously only the first one started got any logs in the file.